# How to use groupby + transform instead of pipe, to calculate linear regressions for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': list('abaab'),
        'val1': range(5),
        'val2': range(2, 7),
        'val3': range(4, 9)
    }
)

  group  val1  val2  val3
0     a     0     2     4
1     b     1     3     5
2     a     2     4     6
3     a     3     5     7
4     b     4     6     8
```

Now I want to calculate linear regressions for each group in column `group` using two of the `vali` columns (potentially all pairs, so I don't want to hardcode column names anywhere).

A potential implementation could look like this based on `pipe`

```
def do_lin_reg_pipe(df, group_col, col1, col2):
    group_names = df[group_col].unique()
    df_subsets = []
    for s in group_names:
        df_subset = df.loc[df[group_col] == s]
        x = df_subset[col1].values
        y = df_subset[col2].values
        slope, intercept, r, p, se = stats.linregress(x, y)
        df_subset = df_subset.assign(
            slope=slope,
            intercept=intercept,
            r=r,
            p=p,
            se=se
        )
        df_subsets.append(df_subset)
    return pd.concat(df_subsets)
```

and then I can use

```
df_linreg_pipe = (
    df.pipe(do_lin_reg_pipe, group_col='group', col1='val1', col2='val3')
      .assign(p=lambda d: d['p'].round(3))
)
```

which gives the desired outcome

```
  group  val1  val2  val3  slope  intercept    r    p   se
0     a     0     2     4    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2     a     2     4     6    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3     a     3     5     7    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
1     b     1     3     5    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4     b     4     6     8    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

What I don't like is that I have to loop through the groups, use and `append` and then also `concat`, so I thought I should somehow use a `groupby` and `transform` but I don't get this to work. The function call should be something like

```
df_linreg_transform = df.copy()
df_linreg_transform[['slope', 'intercept', 'r', 'p', 'se']] = (
    df.groupby('group').transform(do_lin_reg_transform, col1='val1', col2='val3')
)
```

question is how to define `do_lin_reg_transform`; I would like to have something along these lines

```
def do_lin_reg_transform(df, col1, col2):
    
    x = df[col1].values
    y = df[col2].values
    slope, intercept, r, p, se = stats.linregress(x, y)

    return (slope, intercept, r, p, se)
```

but that - of course - crashes with a `KeyError`

> KeyError: 'val1'

How could one implement `do_lin_reg_transform` to make it work with `groupby` and `transform`?

Comment: `transform` apply one operation for each column. You can't use an operation that need 2 columns or more. You don't receive a dataframe for the operation but a series.

Comment: @Corralien: Ok, that's a pity. So, `pipe` is the best option for this problem?

Comment: Maybe not. I think you can use `groupby`. I think about it.

Comment: @Corralien: ok, if you see a solution that involves `groupby` feel free to post it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform is meant to aggregate results for a single column. A regression requires multiple so you should use `apply`.

If you wanted, you could define your aggregation to return a DataFrame as opposed to the Series (so the result doesn't reduce). For this to work, you'd want to make sure you index is unique. Then `concat` the result back so it aligns on the index. You won't have any issues if there's more than 1 grouping column.

```
def group_reg(gp, col1, col2):
    df = pd.DataFrame([stats.linregress(gp[col1], gp[col2])]*len(gp), 
                      columns=['slope', 'intercept', 'r', 'p', 'se'],
                      index=gp.index)
    return df

pd.concat([df, df.groupby('group').apply(group_reg, col1='val1', col2='val3')], axis=1)
```

---

```
  group  val1  val2  val3  slope  intercept    r             p   se
0     a     0     2     4    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
1     b     1     3     5    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.000000e+00  0.0
2     a     2     4     6    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
3     a     3     5     7    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
4     b     4     6     8    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.000000e+00  0.0
```

Comment: Output looks good, let me walk through it and then I get back to you (and upvote etc).

Comment: Ok, works well! Upvoted; will wait with acceptance still a bit to check what else pops up.

Answer (score 3):

As you can't use `groupby...transform` because your computation needs to access multiple columns, the ideas is to use `groupby...apply` with `map` to broadcast the result to each row:

```
cols = ['slope', 'intercept', 'r', 'p', 'se']
lingress = lambda x: stats.linregress(x['val1'], x['val3'])

df[cols] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['group'].map(df.groupby('group').apply(lingress)))
print(df)

# Output
  group  val1  val2  val3  slope  intercept    r             p   se
0     a     0     2     4    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
1     b     1     3     5    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.000000e+00  0.0
2     a     2     4     6    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
3     a     3     5     7    1.0        4.0  1.0  9.003163e-11  0.0
4     b     4     6     8    1.0        4.0  1.0  0.000000e+00  0.0
```

Comment: Nice, works well, too! I turned the `lambda` into a `def` and then don't hardcode the column names; seems to work fine.